# windows filterring platform WFP

Tags: windows, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

hi I want to learn about windows filtering platform I am new i need tutorial or video to help me in my firewall project 
what i really want is to stop packet with specific port and change the port then send the packet
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use NDIS lwf instead of WFP?  On my experience, NDIS is more easy for port processing.  WFP is callout function method, But NDIS have two recv, send function in code.  You can use this function, capture packet(port) and block or change this.  If you want to stop only one port, WFP is also good.
 Anyway, first, you can see Windows Filtering platform Sample in C++   https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-Filtering-Platform-27553baa